# Display data from external XML feed on website using PHP

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, xml-parsing

I need to display data from an external XML feed on my site but I have absolutely no idea where to start. What would be the full PHP code to grab the XML feed and print the following elements into my page:

```
<name></name>
<status></status>
<pin></pin>
<picture>
</picture>
<description></description>
<category name="skills">
  <skill></skill>
</category>
<category name="tools">
  <tool></tool>
  <tool></tool>
  <tool></tool>
</category>
<category name="subjects">
  <subject></subject>
</category>
```

Comment: The XML above is not well-formed as it's missing a declaration and a root element (i.e. a single element/tag that encompasses all other elements). Do you have a fuller example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php built in function called `simplexml_load_string` along with `file_get_contents`.

What the two functions do is convert the url xml feed to a string and then create an object stored into `$xml`.

Resource [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Resource [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
$url = 'yourXMLfeed.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

You can then access your data inside `<name></name>`, etc like so:

`echo $xml->name` will print the data inside of the `name` tags.

If you have a nested xml feed you can also use `foreach` like so:

```
foreach($xml as $x):
 echo $x->name
endforeach;
```

### EDIT

Let say each of your `<tool></tool>` had data ie:

`<tool>Wrench</tool> <tool>Hammer</tool> <tool>Screwdriver</tool>`

You could do a quick `foreach` loop to get the data like so:

```
foreach($xml->category[1] as $tool) {
    echo $tool.' ';
}
```

This would echo out Wrench Hammer Screwdriver

Comment: Ok thanks, but for instance, where there is <category name="tools"> and there is multiple children, how do I show each <tool>

Comment: This can be simplified to `simplexml_load_file('yourXMLfeed.xml');`

Comment: @AlanCarr do you want to show each `<tool>` or the data inside?

Comment: Doesn't he also need a header of some sorts with "style information" ?